# How here the the guest_post() work, The displaying issue in output - image attached and mentioned in the end of the code

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

[My Issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGQGm.png)

```
<?php //sqltest.php

//Part 01 - The first part of the code will establish connection with DB using mysqli method

require_once 'login.php';

$conn = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);

if ($conn->connect_error) die ($conn->connect_error);

// Part - 02 - Here is the method to delete some data using query by taking input and later checking using isset

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset ($_POST['isbn'])){

    $isbn = get_post($conn,'isbn');
    $query ="DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn = '$isbn'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$result) echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>". $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}

//Part 04 - Here is the method to insert some data using query by taking input by get_post method-(see the last code) and checking using isset

if (isset($_POST['author']) &&
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['category']) &&
    isset($_POST['year']) &&
    isset($_POST['isbn'])){

        $author = get_post($conn,'author');
        $title = get_post($conn,'title');
        $category = get_post($conn,'category');
        $year = get_post($conn,'year');
        $isbn = get_post($conn,'isbn');
        $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" . "('$author','$title','$category','$year','$isbn')";

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed:  . $query<br> ". $conn->error. "<br><br>"; 
    }

    //Part - 05 - FORM handler 

    echo <<<_END

    <form action="sqltest.php" 
        method="post">
        <pre> 

        Author <input type = "text" name ="author">
        Title <input type = "text" name = "title">
        Category <input type = "text" name = "category">
        Year <input type = "text" name = "year">
        ISBN <input type = "text" name = "isbn">

        <input type = "submit" value = "ADD RECORD">

        </pre>
        </form>
_END;

// Part - 06 -A new query for showing the whole classics table from DB

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";

$result = $conn->query($query);

if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: ". $conn->error);

    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    for ($j=0; $j<$rows; ++$j){

        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        // Part - 07 The following html code will take the iput for deleting any entry using isbn - refers to 1st part of the code 

        echo <<<_END

        <pre>

        Author $row[0]
        Title $row[1]
        Category $row[2]
        Year $row[3]
        ISBN $row[4]

        </pre>

        <form action = "sqltest.php" method = "post">

        <input type ="hidden" name = "delete" value = "yes">
        <input type = "hiddden" name = "isbn" value = "$row[4]">
        <input type="submit" value = "DELETE RECORD">

        </form>
_END;

    }

    $result->close();
    $conn->close();

    //Part 08 - actually the code begins from here

    function get_post($conn,$var)

    {
        return $conn->real_eascape_string($_POST[$var]); 

        //to avoid special charecter
    }



    ?>
```

/** The code is working very fine. Except two thing: 1. In part 7 of the code i mentioned the isbn number to be keep hidden and only show the delete button. But in output it is showing both number and button. 2. The boxes with the record fields are not set according which is not looking good as expected - i used pre but still it's showing broken output.**/

Comment: For #1, Hidden has three d's in this line : <input type = "hiddden" name = "isbn" value = "$row[4]">

Comment: For #2, it probably makes sense to use a table since this is tabular data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isbn is displayed because you have a spelling issue. You wrote hidden with 3 d‘s in part 7. hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks but still the display is not lined up and showing broken outputs any solution. and can you explain the get post section

Comment: You’re welcome! What do you exactly means with broken? Can you provide a screenshot of that?

Comment: Okay now I see. hcheung gave you a good advice. You should look at html and css.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you have a typo in `hiddden` (correct one should be `hidden`).

For #2, learn how to use css to [style the form](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp). Also learn how to use html [label tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).

Some people suggests to use table for formatting which is not a best practice and should be avoid.

In general, HTML should only contain information about your content, and CSS take care of the presentation of the content. This is called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php //sqltest.php

//Part 01 - The first part of the code will establish connection with DB using mysqli method

require_once 'login.php';

$conn = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);

if ($conn->connect_error) die ($conn->connect_error);

// Part - 02 - Here is the method to delete some data using query by taking input and later checking using isset

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset ($_POST['isbn'])){

    $isbn = get_post($conn,'isbn');
    $query ="DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn = '$isbn'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$result) echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>". $conn->error . "<br><br>";
}

//Part 04 - Here is the method to insert some data using query by taking input by get_post method-(see the last code) and checking using isset

if (isset($_POST['author']) &&
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['category']) &&
    isset($_POST['year']) &&
    isset($_POST['isbn'])){

        $author = get_post($conn,'author');
        $title = get_post($conn,'title');
        $category = get_post($conn,'category');
        $year = get_post($conn,'year');
        $isbn = get_post($conn,'isbn');
        $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" . "('$author','$title','$category','$year','$isbn')";

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed:  . $query<br> ". $conn->error. "<br><br>"; 
    }

    //Part - 05 - FORM handler 

    echo <<<_END

    <form action="sqltest.php" 
        method="post">
        <pre> 

        Author <input type = "text" name ="author">
        Title <input type = "text" name = "title">
        Category <input type = "text" name = "category">
        Year <input type = "text" name = "year">
        ISBN <input type = "text" name = "isbn">

        <input type = "submit" value = "ADD RECORD">

        </pre>
        </form>
_END;

// Part - 06 -A new query for showing the whole classics table from DB

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";

$result = $conn->query($query);

if(!$result) die ("Database access failed: ". $conn->error);

    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    for ($j=0; $j<$rows; ++$j){

        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        // Part - 07 The following html code will take the iput for deleting any entry using isbn - refers to 1st part of the code 

        echo <<<_END

        <pre>

        Author $row[0]
        Title $row[1]
        Category $row[2]
        Year $row[3]
        ISBN $row[4]

        </pre>

        <form action = "sqltest.php" method = "post">

        <input type ="hidden" name = "delete" value = "yes">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "isbn" value = "$row[4]">
        <input type="submit" value = "DELETE RECORD">

        </form>
_END;

    }

    $result->close();
    $conn->close();

    //Part 08 - actually the code begins from here

    function get_post($conn,$var)

    {
        return $conn->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]); 

        //to avoid special charecter
    }



    ?>
```